# Cant remove the right margin,CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the live server on and i tried making changes on almost every element (setting the margin-right to be 0px,decreasing the padding,etc..) and nothing helped me fix the problem. It's all scalled good but it shows the overflow option so u can scroll on the right,and it's really rude and not needed. But i cant find where's the problem.

```
    html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
ul, li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-up {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #E28B65;
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-up-ul,li a{
    margin-right: -100px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}
.nav-up-ul,li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
.icons {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 340px;
}
.fb {
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.nav-up-ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
    transition: .3s;
}
.fb:hover{
    opacity: 30%;
    transition: .2s;
}
.btn,a{
    color: black;
}
.ukim-logo {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav-main {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFFBF6;
}
h1 {
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.nav-main p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
.nav-main img {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #E28B65;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
.nav-main a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: -11px;
}
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(185, 113, 82);
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.nav-down {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #E28B65;
    height: 25px;
}
.nav-down li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: -30px;
}
.nav-down li a:hover{
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.mySlides {display: none;}    
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
.header-grid{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.small-sep{
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px 66px;
  column-gap: 150px;
  row-gap: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  grid-template-areas: "box1 box7" "box2 box8" "box3 box9" "box4 box10" "box5 box11" "box6 box12" "box13 box14" "box15 box16" "box17 box18" "box19 box20" "box21 box22" "box23 box24";
}
.hovered:hover{
  background-color: #E28B65;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  transition: .4s;
}
.separator-grid{
  width: 110px;
  height: 1120px;
  margin-top: -1150px;
  margin-left: 418px;
  position: relative;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5,.box6,.box7,.box8,.box9,.box10,.box11,.box12,.box13,.box14,.box15,.box16,.box17,.box18,.box19,.box20,.box21,.box22,.box23,.box24{
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-color: #E28B65;
  background-color: #FFFBF6;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box1 { 
  grid-area: box1;
}

.box2 {
   grid-area: box2; 
  }

.box3 { 
  grid-area: box3; 
}

.box4 { 
  grid-area: box4; 
}

.box5 { 
  grid-area: box5; 
}

.box6 { 
  grid-area: box6; 
}

.box7 { 
  grid-area: box7; 
}

.box8 { 
  grid-area: box8; 
}

.box9 { 
  grid-area: box9; 
}

.box10 { 
  grid-area: box10; 
}

.box11 { 
  grid-area: box11; 
}

.box12 { 
  grid-area: box12; 
}

.box12 p{
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.box13 { 
  grid-area: box13; 
}
.box14 { 
  grid-area: box14; 
}
.box14 p{
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.box15 { 
  grid-area: box15; 
}
.box16 { 
  grid-area: box16; 
}
.box16 p{
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.box17 { 
  grid-area: box17; 
}
.box18 { 
  grid-area: box18; 
}
.box19 { 
  grid-area: box19; 
}
.box19 p{
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.box20 { 
  grid-area: box20; 
}
.box20 p{
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.box21 { 
  grid-area: box21; 
}
.box22 { 
  grid-area: box22; 
}
.box23 { 
  grid-area: box23; 
}
.box24 { 
  grid-area: box24; 
}
footer{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 160px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 160px;
  background-color: #E28B65;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.footer-logo{
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
footer p{
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
}
.partner {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.footer-down{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #673520;
  margin-top: -16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer-down p{
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.footer-down a{
  color: white;
}
.footer-down a:hover{
  color: black;
}
```

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>УКИМ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="nav-up">
        <ul class="nav-up-ul">
            <li><a href="#">European Information & Innovation Centre Macedonia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Институт "Конфуциј"</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Руски МИР</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Македонско-американска алумни асоцијација</a></li>
            <ul class="icons">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/fb.svg" alt="facebook" class="fb"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/yt.svg" alt="facebook" class="fb"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ig.svg" alt="facebook" class="fb"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/tw.svg" alt="facebook" class="fb"></a>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <nav>

        <ul class="nav-main">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ukim-logo.png" alt="ukim-logo" class="ukim-logo"></a>
            <h1>Универзитет "Св. Кирил и Методиј" во Скопје</h1>

            <img src="images/phone.svg" alt="phone">
            <p> Централа : 2 3293-293
            <br>Факс : 2 3293-202</p>

            <img src="images/mail.svg" alt="mail">
            <p> Централа : 2 3293-293
            <br>Факс : 2 3293-202</p>

            <img src="images/location.svg" alt="location">
            <p> Централа : 2 3293-293
            <br>Факс : 2 3293-202</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn animated tada">УПИСИ ВО ТЕК</a>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-down">
            <li><a href="#">Универзитет</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Структура</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Органи и тела на УКИМ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Настава и студенти</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Наука</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Докторски студии</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Меѓународна соработка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">МСМЈЛК</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">УКЦ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Документи</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="slideshow-container animated zoomIn">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Нов дизајн на веб страната на УКИМ</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Пример</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Пример</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Пример</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
        </div>

        <div class="header-grid">
          <h2>Факултети</h2>
          <img src="images/smallsep.svg" alt="smallsep" class="small-sep">
        </div>

        <section>
        <div class="grid">
          <img src="images/separator.svg" alt="separator" class="separator-grid">
          <div class="box1 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="100">
            <p>Архитектонски факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box2 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Градежен факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box3 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Економски факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box4 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Машински факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box5 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Медицински факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box6 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Педагошки факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box7 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="100">
            <p>Правен факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box8 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Природно-математички факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box9 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Стоматолошки фкаултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box10 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Технолошко-металуршки факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box11 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за ветеринарна медицина</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box12 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за дизајн и технологии на мебел и ентериер</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box13 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет драмски уметности</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box14 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за електротехника и информациски технологии</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box15 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за земјоделски науки и храна</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box16 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за информатички науки и компјутерско инжињерство</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box17 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за ликовни уметности</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box18 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за музичка уметност</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box19 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за физичко образование,спорт и здравје</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box20 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Факултет за шумарски науки,пејсажна архитектура и екоинжењеринг "Ханс Ем"</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box21 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Фармацевтски факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box22 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Филозофски факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box23 hovered" data-aos="slide-right" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Филолошки факултет</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box24 hovered" data-aos="slide-left" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-offset="50">
            <p>Институти</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <img src="images/partner.svg" alt="partners" class="partner">
          <img src="images/partner.svg" alt="partners" class="partner">
          <img src="images/partner.svg" alt="partners" class="partner">
          <img src="images/partner.svg" alt="partners" class="partner">
          <img src="images/ukim-logo.png" alt="logo-ukim" class="footer-logo">
          <p>Работното време<br>
            на Централната стручна и административна служба – Ректоратот е секој работен ден, од понеделник до петок,
            од 8,00 до 16,00 ч.<br><br>
            Дневна пауза<br>
            од 12,00 до 12,30 ч.<br><br>
            Приемни саати, работни средби и комуникација<br>
            на вработените на Централната стручна и административна служба – Ректорат со надворешни лица секој работен ден
            од 14,00 до 16,00 ч.</p>
          </footer>
          <div class="footer-down">
            <p>© 2020. Универзитет „Св. Кирил и Методиј“ во Скопје. Сите права се задржани. Политика за приватност Изработено од : <a href="#">© Atlas Solutions Inc.</a></p>
          </div>
        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }
            </script>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
            <script>
              AOS.init();
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML Is invalid. Ul can only have li as children

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed it right now! I had to hide the overflow on the grid div using 
`overflow: hidden;`